# Error: the command ( (from my_script) could not be found within PATH

Tags: python, bash, pipenv

While working on a Python FastAPI project using Pipenv and Pytest, I was asked to write a Pipenv script to run the tests.

Project has the following structure:

```
.
├── app
|   ├── main.py
│   ├── my_package
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── (project folders)
│   │   └── tests
|   |       └── tests.py
│   └── __pycache__
└──(deployment scripts and folders, Pipfile, Dokerfile, etc)
```

I'd like to run Pytest on tests.py from the top structure (./app/.../tests.py). At least for now.

As recommended [here](https://superuser.com/questions/271986/execute-a-command-from-another-directory-in-bash), I currently run them from the top with:

```
( cd app ; python -m pytest my_package/tests/tests.py )
```

... which works as expected.

However, when I add that my Pipfile-scripts-section:

```
[scripts]
my_script = "( cd app ; python -m pytest my_package/tests/tests.py )"
```

... run it with:

```
pipenv run my_script
```

I get the error:

```
Error: the command ( (from my_script) could not be found within PATH.
```

I've also tried:

```
[scripts]
my_script = "cd app && python -m pytest my_package/tests/tests.py"
```

... which returns another similar error:

```
Error: the command cd (from my_script) could not be found within PATH.
```

So it's clear I'm wrong to use it as bash aliases.
I've tried searching for more documentation on how the [scripts] section works as I, but I've had no luck (yet).

Comment: If you add `echopath = "echo %PATH%"` and run it, what will be printed? Apart from that, pipenv evaluates `cd x && y` to `cd 'x && y'` on my Linux and MacOS machines, failing on finding the directory `x && y`, so this probably won't bring you far anyway.

Comment: Could not do what you asked, as I got a Error:
Error: the command echopath (from my_script_test) could not be found within PATH.

But thank you for the info about how pipenv evals a cmd :)

@wjandrea 's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the tools you're using, but the error message suggests that it's looking for an executable. `(` is part of shell syntax, and `cd` is a shell builtin, not an executable. Try this:

```
my_script = "bash -c 'cd app && python -m pytest my_package/tests/tests.py'"
```

Here `bash` is the executable, and `-c` makes it run your snippet.

BTW, keep in mind that `cd` can fail, so the script should bail out if it does.

Comment: Also, it bails out perfectly thanks to  '&&', thank you for that as well